# Must wait for AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I make multiple AJAX calls on a web page,and they take a lot of time to complete (5 minutes). During those calls, if I try to go to another page on my website (with a new window or not), I must wait for the AJAX calls to finish before the page loads.

I make the calls asynchronously:

```
ajax_seek=$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url_tracks,
       data: { youtubes : tab_tracks },
       sucess:function(a){
           console.log(a);
       }
    });
```

Anybody have an explanation ?

Comment: Are you making these calls synchronously?

Comment: Sounds like you are making synchronous ajax, which will block.

Comment: Direct reason is you're using synchronous AJAX requests which lock the browser window until they're complete. The broader reason is that your application isn't designed very well, as it shouldn't need to depend on these calls. Definitely not good for UX.

Comment: That sounds rather like you are using sessions – and as long as your AJAX call is running, the session file is blocked, so that other scripts trying to access the same session have to wait until the session lock is released. Calling `session_write_close` as soon as possible in your script that you call via AJAX should fix that (if possible; if you need write access to the session all the way through, then there’s little you can do).

Comment: How many AJAX calls are made per page? Ideally you should only have one, and if there more than two or three on page load, that's quite a lot of extra work for the server. Is the five minutes a result of a long-running task, or just the sheer number of AJAX calls?

Comment: If you've found an answer, please add it as an answer, and mark it as accepted, rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like CBroe said the answer was to put "session_write_close();" in my php file wich is called 
with ajax. And it worked :)